# How to calculate average daily sales for each month in a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I need to calculate the averages I have in a month.  What I'm expecting is to calculate 936, 184, 943, and 230 and get an average of 573.

[image]

However, when Excel calculates these values in a pivot table, it gives me 28.

[image]

Why doesn't this give me the average I want? How can I make my pivot table do this?